# What is this WordPress error I received after installing a new theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, location, wordpress-theming

I have this error on my WordPress

```
Undefined option "optimize_css_and_js_loading" called from:
Array[4]
   file => "/srv/htdocs/wp-content/themes/gamic/plugins/trx_addons/trx_addons.php"
   line => 2048
   function => "trx_addons_get_option"
   args => Array[2]
      0 => "optimize_css_and_js_loading"
      1 => "none"
```